# pg_search seems to ignore `using` for associated_against

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I am trying to figure out why the `using` specifications does not works for the `associated against` fields. My code is:

```
 include PgSearch

 pg_search_scope :search,
    { 
     :associated_against => {
       :client => [:name, :email],
     },
     :against => [:description],
     using: {
       tsearch: {},
       trigram:    {threshold:  0.1}
     }
    }
```

For field `description` it works well.

Any tips here ?

Thanks in advance.